# android webview taking up entire screen

Tags: android, webview

Im very new to developing android applications and im messing around with making a basic web browser. So far Ive got it more or less working how I want it to. The problem im encountering is that some websites load full screen and cover up my buttons and editText for URL. For example websites like reddit.com or notcot.org display in the given area fort the webview but websites like facebook.com or yahoo.com will reload and take up the entire screen covering my buttons and editText bar leaving me to use the emulator back button and not the one I made. Im really not sure what the issue is since it only seems to happen with some sites and not other. 
here is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ShowWeb" 
>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:src="@drawable/leftarrow" 
    />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:inputType="textUri" 
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:maxWidth="225dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>

   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/goButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:src="@drawable/go" 
    />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/forwardButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:src="@drawable/rightarrow" 
     />   

  </LinearLayout>

   <WebView
       android:id="@+id/webBrowser"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_below="@+id/linear1" 
   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the Java code is

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class ShowWeb extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
ImageButton forward,back,go;
WebView wv;
String urlString;
EditText et;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_web);
    forward = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.forwardButton);
    forward.setOnClickListener(this);
    back = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.backButton);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);
    go = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.goButton);
    go.setOnClickListener(this);
    wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webBrowser);
    wv.setInitialScale(50);
    wv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    et.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() 
    {
         public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
         {
         if((event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&& 
                 keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
         { 
             try
             {
               URL url = new URL(et.getText().toString());
               urlString=url.toString();
               wv.setInitialScale(50);
               wv.loadUrl(urlString);

             }
             catch(MalformedURLException e)
             {
                urlString = et.getText().toString(); 
                wv.setInitialScale(50);
                wv.loadData(urlString, "text/html", "UTF-8");


             }
             return true;
         }        
         else    
             return false;
         }
    }
    );
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.show_web, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch(v.getId()) 
    {
        case R.id.forwardButton:
            if(wv.canGoForward())
                wv.goForward();
                et.setText(wv.getUrl());
            break;
        case R.id.backButton:
            if(wv.canGoBack())
                wv.goBack();
                et.setText(wv.getUrl());

            break;
            case R.id.goButton:
            wv.setInitialScale(50);
            wv.loadUrl(urlString);

    }

}

}
```

Thanks for any tips or advice on whatever im just not seeing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to override WebViewClient as in code below:

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then in your onCreate method:

```
wm.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

All that will allow you to open links inside your webview and you will always see your buttons.

Comment: Yep, that is it, there are a lot of different useful settings in WebView, you better have to read API

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use the relative layout and his proprieties?
you can solve this problem using layout_below.

EX: you have 3 itens (Button 1, button2 and WebView)

```
Button1 id is @+id/button1
Button2 id is @+id/button2
WebView id is @+id/webView

button1 layout_above = "@+id/webView"
button2 layout_right = "@id/button1"
webview layout_below = "@id/button1"
```

ps: you can use this properties with linear layout too, if they was  children from a relative layout.

sry about my grammar, english isn't my main language =[.